# dynamically create a button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, dynamic

In Visual Studio C# windows form how do I dynamically create a button each time an item is inserted into a listbox ?

When the created button is clicked it has to remove the inserted item from the listbox.

I want to add the button th this:

```
 if (comboBox4.Text != "" && listBox1.Text != "" && comboBox3.Text != "")
  {
     string ha = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
     Clipboard.SetText(comboBox4.Text + "stk " + ha + " i farve " + comboBox3.Text);
     listBox2.Items.Add(comboBox4.Text + "stk " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() +
                        " " + comboBox3.Text);
  }
```

Comment: Please add what you tried so far and what technology you use (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Create a button and add to the form.

Pseudo-code (not the complete solution, only the main login behind it):

```
public class MyEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public ListBoxValue lbv;
}

...
listBox2.Items.Add(comboBox4.Text + "stk " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " " + comboBox3.Text);

Button x = new Button();
x.Text = "whatever";
x.Top = some coordinate;
x.Left = some coordinate;

MyEventArgs me = new MyEventArgs();
me.lbv = inserted lisbox item reference;

x.Click += new ClickHandler(this, me);
myForm.Controls.Add(x);

...

private void ClickHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    listbox.Items.Remove(e.lbv);
}
```